# Backup SQLite database to email?

Tags: android, database, email, backup, restore

I have an app with SQLite database. I want to add an oportunity to do backup/restoration of database. I see a lot of answers about backup to SD card. But what if a device has no SD card? How to implement backup? Or maybe I can send database.db file to email, that user pointed, and download it from there when it's needed and add to application?
What can you advice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way that can help you do that. however you can do a select on all your tables, put them in a CSV,XML or JSON file and then compress them.